# Was told the post I edited in review had other edits but there is nothing else in revision history

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, banner

On finishing an edit from the Suggested Edits queue, I got a message about other saved edits, linked to the [post I just edited from review](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69329200/revisions), but there are no other edits listed other than mine and the edit I was improving. The [author of the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/122548111?noredirect=1) says they didn't make any further changes to the post:

> Nope, I just edited the post one time (added java tag), probably I had a second tab opened on another stack overflow page but nothing else if I remember well.

There's nothing in the timeline other than me improving the edit.
So why did I get this message?

[image: This post has been edited 2 times since you began]

(The question shown in the image is not the one I edited but the one after it in the queue.)

Comment: It is possible for the author of the suggested edit to edit it a bit further. Maybe they done so and that got merged in their original edit?

Comment: Or do you mean that you reviewed this https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29916532 and got a notification that a _different_ question got edited 2 times? If yes, then this looks like a weird bug. Is it possible that you had that other review still open in a different tab?

Comment: @Tom This is the post I reviewed and edited, and where the banner links: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69329200/revisions. If it was the editor making a revision (no way for me to tell), the message is fairly useless and confusing. (I did not see it while editing, only after.) No second tabs open.

Comment: Well, maybe a mod and provide more insight about what had happened here. Regarding *"the message is fairly useless and confusing"* ... confusing, yes maybe, but not useless. The engine needs to merge both edits and when your edit started on a previous revision, then it might overwrite newer revision. So it tries to tell you that so you can think about re-starting your edit from the newest revision.